# Hardware faults on graphics cards

Tags: gpu, nvidia

I am trying to get a second mining rig setup and I have been having a lot of issues with the video cards that I have bought off ebay.

I get a lot of errors like this from nvidia-smi:

`Failed to determine the device handle for GPU 0000:08:00.0: GPU is lost. Reboot the system to recover this GPU.`

Should I return these gpus or is this just something that happens? I don't get these errors on my existing rig and this is with some light over clocking (about +1000 on nvidia-settings for memory. Normal overclocking on there is +1400)